# On Mac, are there keyboard shortcuts to create a new Space? Or at least any way to automate this process with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I want to not have to use the mouse to create Spaces. I want to use the keyboard for that.

Comment: How do you create a new space with the mouse? Do you want to switch to another Space or actually extend the number of Spaces defined?

Comment: What's your working practise that needs to generate new spaces with sufficient frequency it needs a hot key? You can set any maximum Space requirement then just leave it as-is. There's no need to create/destroy them repeatedly.